# Unable to get Polylines coordinates of TPL Maps

Tags: android, maps, polyline

I am using [this](https://api.tplmaps.com/apiportal/#/portal/sdk-doc) map for an app, (Yes,I know I should be using Google Maps but my boss says I need to use this). I have integrated the map but the problem is that I am trying to draw a polyline between two points I have read the [doc](https://api.tplmaps.com/android-doc/).
And went for the **Polylines** Section under **Draw markers and shapes** ( *At the end of [doc](https://api.tplmaps.com/android-doc/)*) the problem is it just draws a straight path between the two points.
[image]
I also checked the **TPLMapsAndroidSdkSamples** given in the doc. We can see that in the [ActivityRouting](https://github.com/TPLMaps/TPLMapsAndroidSdkSamples/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/tplmaps/android/sdk/samples/activities/ActivityRouting.java) class I modified the `onMapRoutingOverview` Method to get the values of `X` & `Y`

```
public void onMapRoutingOverview(ArrayList<Place> endPoints, ArrayList<TPLRoute> routes) {
                    StringBuilder response;
                    response = new StringBuilder("Start: " + endPoints.get(0).getName()
                            + " (" + endPoints.get(0).getY() +
                            "," + endPoints.get(0).getX() + ")\n");
                    response.append("End: ").append(endPoints.get(1).getName()).append(" (")
                            .append(endPoints.get(1).getY()).append(",")
                            .append(endPoints.get(1).getX()).append(")\n");
                    int routeNo = 0;
                    for (TPLRoute route : routes) {
                        response.append("\n\nRoute ").append(++routeNo)
                                .append("\nRoute Length (In Meters): ").append(route.getTotalLength())
                                .append("\n").append("Route Time (In Milliseconds): ")
                                .append(route.getTotalTime()).append("\n");
                        response.append("Turns: \n");
                        for (Place p : route.getListWayPoints()) {
                            response.append(p.getX()).append("\n")
                            .append(p.getY()).append("\n");
                        }
                        response.append("-----------------------------------");
                    }
                    Log.d("TESTING",response.toString()+" ::: ");
                }
```

I'm getting this in the `Log` The 2 coordinates that it is giving me are the ones that I set for `pickup` and`destination` But I need the ones in the middle to draw around the roads
 .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a different approach for this such as Google Places API or similar and since Google jacked up the prices I went for [GraphHopper](https://docs.graphhopper.com/#tag/Routing-API).
It returns a JSONArray which you can decode to get your polylines and draw them on your TPL map, Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TPL maps you need to use the API from the developer dashboard.
Make sure that you ACTIVATE/ENABLE that api before using it.